# JavaScript Mini-Max Sum - Returns 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to resolve the Mini-Max Sum Challenge from HackerRank. Why my code returns 0?
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem

Been trying different codes and still doesn't work.

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    let maxSum = 0;
    let minSum = 0;
    arr.sort();

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.leight; ++i) {
        minSum += arr[i];
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.leight; ++i) {
        maxSum += arr[i];
    }
    console.log(minSum, maxSum)

}
```

I expect a output like 10 14, but the actual output is 0 0.

Comment: It's "length" not "leight"

Comment: Also you should explain what the code is supposed to do *in your question* not in some linked external resource.

Comment: You know how to use `console.log()`, so you should be using it to debug. That would at least narrow down the possible issues to a specific point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your `arr.length` typos and make sure that the min loop starts at 0 and ends at `arr.length - 1` instead of `arr.length`.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function miniMaxSum(arr) {
  let maxSum = 0;
  let minSum = 0;
  arr.sort();

  console.log(arr);

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; ++i) {
    minSum += arr[i];
  }
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    maxSum += arr[i];
  }
  console.log(minSum, maxSum)
}

miniMaxSum(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code. It should be `arr.length`

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
let maxSum = 0;
let minSum = 0;
arr.sort();

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    minSum += arr[i];
}
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    maxSum += arr[i];
}
console.log(minSum, maxSum)
```

}

Comment: const length = arr.length;

    const sum = arr.sort().reduce((a,b) => a+b);
    const max = sum - arr[0];
    const min = sum - arr[length-1];

    return [min,max]